# Failed Review Audit - Reopen question after typo was fixed

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3797756), and it seems unfair.

The "show differences" tab showed one word changed from `interestring` to `interesting`, with no other revisions. This seems like more of a trick than an audit. If a question is closed, fixing a minor typo will *not* make it a valid question afterwards. I assumed (apparently wrongly) that the question was closed for a valid reason. Am I not to assume that?

I understand that a question may have been hastily or unfairly closed, but isn't that why close votes are reviewed and audited as well? I also understand that a question such as this with tags on which I am unfamiliar should probably be skipped.

Nevertheless, I recommend that the reopen queue have audits with **clearly** bad questions which have been edited to make them **clearly** good questions, or just have **clearly** good questions with no revision history.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't assume that the question was closed for a valid reason. Part of the reason for re-opening questions it to act as a fall-back for when a question is incorrectly closed. By denying people that chance you're actively working against people trying to do the correct thing.

Approach each question in the re-open queue separately. If *you* think, in isolation, that the question should be re-opened (remembering the guidance in help etc) then vote to re-open.

Don't assume that people know everything, or were correct previously.

Comment: Or click skip when you smell this flavor of rat.